# How to split a large list into rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

I have a problem with my list. My task is generate the big with the random list which consist of  10 smaller list with 10 random numbers. I have a correct code generate 10x random list in one big list, but now I need to separate each smaller list because each have to be  in the new line.

This is my code:

```
def generate_random_number_list_10(len_of_elements):
single_list_of_10_random_numbers=[]
for _variable_1 in range (len_of_elements):
    random_number=random.randint(1,100)
    single_list_of_10_random_numbers.append(random_number)
return single_list_of_10_random_numbers

def generate_random_number_list_10x10_1(amount_of_lists):
main_list=[]
for _variable_1 in range (amount_of_lists):
    singlelist=generate_random_number_list_10(5)
    main_list.append(singlelist)
print(main_list)
generate_random_number_list_10x10_1(10)
```

this is my result:

```
[[45, 35, 90, 12, 13, 80, 33, 17, 50, 47], [33, 92, 55, 26, 60, 51, 78, 62, 35, 3], [87, 79, 4, 10, 57, 8, 59, 75, 59, 85], [33, 15, 10, 100, 79, 74, 57, 46, 14, 37], [93, 15, 29, 35, 54, 24, 24, 39, 21, 62], [55, 90, 8, 33, 6, 29, 19, 5, 97, 93], [51, 27, 14, 18, 45, 29, 83, 94, 34, 91], [66, 92, 40, 36, 72, 46, 77, 77, 89, 64], [89, 84, 36, 14, 96, 81, 57, 65, 51, 56], [97, 100, 94, 58, 26, 18, 6, 1, 88, 46]]
```

but I need something like this:

```
[45, 35, 90, 12, 13, 80, 33, 17, 50, 47]
[33, 92, 55, 26, 60, 51, 78, 62, 35, 3]
etc...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can unpack them and use `sep` parameter in `print`.

```
print(*list_of_lists,sep='\n')

[45, 35, 90, 12, 13, 80, 33, 17, 50, 47]
[33, 92, 55, 26, 60, 51, 78, 62, 35, 3]
[87, 79, 4, 10, 57, 8, 59, 75, 59, 85]
[33, 15, 10, 100, 79, 74, 57, 46, 14, 37]
[93, 15, 29, 35, 54, 24, 24, 39, 21, 62]
[55, 90, 8, 33, 6, 29, 19, 5, 97, 93]
[51, 27, 14, 18, 45, 29, 83, 94, 34, 91]
[66, 92, 40, 36, 72, 46, 77, 77, 89, 64]
[89, 84, 36, 14, 96, 81, 57, 65, 51, 56]
[97, 100, 94, 58, 26, 18, 6, 1, 88, 46]
```

Comment: 1) but I need a one big list which consist of 10 smaller

2) how I can unpacked in my code main_list ?

Comment: In your question, you mentioned you already have a list of lists. *this is my result:* @KonradLubelski

Comment: @KonradLubelski `*` is used for unpacking and for unpacking your `main_list` do this `print(*main_list)`.

Comment: ok, this works, thanks but i think also about another case if I not want to unpacked big list , only smaller lists shows in new line of big list. How can this do?

Answer (score 1):

one way will be to print the numbers once they have been produced:

```
def generate_random_number_list_10x10_1(amount_of_lists):
    for _variable_1 in range (amount_of_lists):
        print(generate_random_number_list_10(amount_of_lists))

generate_random_number_list_10x10_1(10)
```

output:

```
[49, 48, 9, 53, 17, 11, 52, 29, 72, 18]
[1, 3, 35, 73, 3, 14, 75, 87, 43, 4]
[61, 89, 13, 76, 41, 20, 79, 29, 59, 84]
[13, 25, 34, 6, 89, 60, 44, 49, 64, 96]
[49, 70, 12, 12, 49, 74, 58, 94, 33, 16]
[36, 73, 37, 51, 25, 43, 91, 67, 94, 56]
[90, 45, 40, 40, 14, 82, 39, 54, 27, 55]
[4, 52, 78, 53, 57, 31, 17, 31, 2, 38]
[91, 67, 57, 14, 33, 25, 8, 93, 37, 44]
[59, 60, 48, 44, 3, 70, 85, 13, 38, 13]
```

pay attention to your question, it is a difference between what your code generates and what you say it does, `singlelist=generate_random_number_list_10(5)` will give you lists with 5 elemnts inside

Comment: ok, this works, thanks but i think also about another case if I not want to unpacked big list , only smaller lists shows in new line of big list. How can this do?